# Samsung devices show extra gap in front of actionbar home button

Tags: android-actionbar, samsung-mobile, android-homebutton

Looks like it is a bug, but Galaxy S5 and Note 2 add an extra space in front of home drawable when setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() is set to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finished by enabling home as up indicator as the following:

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

but then hiding it inside styles.xml:

`<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>`

Comment: Alexey, if you're using Android support library, you should possibly also set <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>